# How to escape commas on mysql queries

Tags: mysql

I have some text and I want to add it to a mysql table. The problem is that the text includes commas, and when I try to do an `INSERT`, it detects more arguments.

Let's see an example.

`INSERT INTO 'video' (tittle_id, text, level) VALUES (20140531190530, Hi, this is the video text, I hope you like it, 90)`

As you can see, it detects `Hi`, `this is the video text`, and `I hope you like it` as three different arguments.

Is there a way to solve it?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: its not about escaping comma you need to use single quote for the string values and if possible PDO

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

Comment: I gave a plus point for the question, after someone downvoted, as when eg doing group_concat of distinct values, and data wrangling result in another query, I personally find it easy to forget, even momentarily, this is what is going on - I searched for escape commas in mysql, as others may do, and am reminded neatly here, that I need to remember some of the group_concat results have comma in the string, so need put quotes in right place when constructing new query!

I think this is good question title and question, so people can quickly correct a common misunderstanding I suspect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using single quotes:

```
INSERT INTO 'video' (tittle_id, text, level) 
VALUES (20140531190530, 'Hi, this is the video text, I hope you like it', 90)
```

Comment: No. I add this code to the query: `$db->query($q) or die ("Query failed due to: ".mysql_error());`

But it only prints:
`Query failed due to: `

Comment: @Neoares: What are the types and sizes of the fields?

Comment: I'm using varchars and text. And all paramerers are smaller than the size of varchars.

Comment: Oh wait, the text contained accents, and the tables are in `latin1_swedish_ci` I removed the accents and it was all ok.

Comment: BTW, your answer to my bad question was ok, so thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

Put Hi, this is the video text, I hope you like it inside single quotes, like this:

```
INSERT INTO 'video' (tittle_id, text, level) 
VALUES (20140531190530, 'Hi, this is the video text, I hope you like it', 90)
```